# C++ equivalent to C# Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()

Tags: c++, encoding, ascii

I come from C#, I had a line :

```
 byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("myString");
```

How can I have an equivalent in C++ to get a `std::vector<unsigned char>` ?

Comment: Do you really need it? What is it what you want to achieve with a `std::vector<unsigned char>` that you cannot achieve using a `std::basic_string<unsigned char>`?

Comment: Do you want to convert from one charset to another? In that case, have a look at [`std::codecvt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt). If you just need `unsigned char` as `byte`: They are the same thing, no need to convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should this do the trick ?

```
unsigned char buffer[mystring.length()];
memcpy(buffer, mystring.data(), mystring.length());
```

Comment: Indeed, I thought it would be more complicated

Comment: It is very much more complicated because your C# code does so much more. If this C++ code is good for you then either your .NET string always contains only [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) or your C# code is wrong.